# After adding performSegueWithIdentifier() call, two different segues are created

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I am using performSegueWithIdentifier() when a button is clicked so that I can pass the right info to my next ViewController. When I click the button, it moves on to a new view blank view and then opens the view that I wanted with the information given with the performSegueWithIdentifier() call. This requires the user to hit the back button 2 times just to get back to the main view.

Is there a way to make sure that prepareForSegue() is not automatically called since I am using performSegueWithIdentifier()? I have a feeling this is happening because I call prepareForSegue() with the performSegueWithIdentifier() call and then it is called a second time automatically.

Here is my code that I use the performSegueWithIdentifier() method:

```
if (page == 1)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time1" sender:self];
else if (page == 2
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time2" sender:self];
else if (page == 3)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time3" sender:self];
else if (page == 4)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time4" sender:self];
else if (page == 5)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time5" sender:self];
else if (page == 6)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time6" sender:self];
else if (page == 7)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time7" sender:self];
else if (page == 8)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time8" sender:self];
else if (page == 9)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time9" sender:self];
else if (page == 10)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time10" sender:self];
else if (page == 11)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time11" sender:self];
else if (page == 12)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time12" sender:self];
else if (page == 13)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"time13" sender:self];
```

here is my prepareForSegue() method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time1"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time2"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time3"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time4"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time5"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time6"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time7"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time8"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time9"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time10"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time11"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time12"] ||
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"time13"])
    {
        InfoViewController *ivc = [segue destinationViewController];
        if (_stringText != nil)
            ivc.viewText = _stringText;
    }//end if
}//end prepareForSegue
```

Comment: You should try to do all that code with some loops, just a suggestion to improve your code :)

Comment: @LinusG. Okay thanks but what about the question?

Comment: No idea  otherwise I would've answered as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actions are you segueing on? You're performSegueWithIdentifier method shouldn't be calling itself, that is definitely why you are getting two back buttons. Do you have this hooked up in storyboards as well? You might not even need the performSegueWithIdentifier call at all if you have your segues set up in storyboard, and then you just prepareForSegue for each.

Comment: I do have it setup in my storyboard as well but I thought that is how I was supposed to do it. I control-dragged the button to the next view controller so that it would show the next view controller, I named that segue "time1", and then in the code I implemented the performSegueWithIdentifier. I do need to use this method call. Am I not supposed to set it up in my storyboard as well? If so how would I give an identifier for the segue?

Comment: So it depends where you're hooking it up...are these on buttons, cells, what? If you control clicked from view controller to view controller, then you'd want to call perform. If you control clicked from button to view controller, then you don't need to call perform. I hope that helps

Comment: These are buttons. I clicked the button to the view controller but my issue before was that I needed to call perform in order to make sure that the next view controller receives the correct string. As you can see in my prepare, I am giving a NSAttributedString to the next view controller. This string varies based on which button was clicked. This is why I call perform so that I use the right string.

Comment: The prepare call is setting up those strings though, not perform, right?

Comment: prepare is setting initializing a string in my second view controller to the string that is already set in my first view controller. perform is calling prepare based on which button was pressed.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, then, is that in the button's IBAction code, that's where you should be calling performSegue, NOT in performSegue itself

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75321/discussion-between-bhendricks-and-saboehnke).